# Thread.critical not working in ruby 2.5.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.5

I'm using ruby2.5.0 and I have the below function as part of my script. When I run it I get the below error:

> `ensure in get_database_connection': undefined method`critical=' for
>   Thread:Class (NoMethodError)

I understand the for ruby1.9.0 and above, Thread.critical is no longer supported so how can I edit my function to make it run under ruby2.5.0 ?

Thanks.

```
    # Geodict
# Copyright (C) 2010 Pete Warden <pete@petewarden.com>
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

require 'rubygems'

require 'postgres'
require 'set'

# Some hackiness to include the library script, even if invoked from another directory
require File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'dstk_config')

# Global holder for the database connections
$connections = {}

# The main entry point. This function takes an unstructured text string and returns a list of all the
# fragments it could identify as locations, together with lat/lon positions
def find_locations_in_text(text)

  current_index = text.length-1
  result = []
  $tokenized_words = {}

  setup_countries_cache()
  setup_regions_cache()

  # This loop goes through the text string in *reverse* order. Since locations in English are typically
  # described with the broadest category last, preceded by more and more specific designations towards
  # the beginning, it simplifies things to walk the string in that direction too
  while current_index>=0 do

    current_word, pulled_index, ignored_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    lower_word = current_word.downcase
    could_be_country = $countries_cache.has_key?(lower_word)
    could_be_region = $regions_cache.has_key?(lower_word)

    if not could_be_country and not could_be_region
      current_index = pulled_index
      next
    end

    # This holds the results of the match function for the final element of the sequence. This lets us
    # optimize out repeated calls to see if the end of the current string is a country for example
    match_cache = {}
    token_result = nil

    # These 'token sequences' describe patterns of discrete location elements that we'll look for.
    $token_sequences.each() do |token_sequence|

      # The sequences are specified in the order they'll occur in the text, but since we're walking
      # backwards we need to reverse them and go through the sequence in that order too
      token_sequence = token_sequence.reverse

      # Now go through the sequence and see if we can match up all the tokens in it with parts of
      # the string
      token_result = nil
      token_index = current_index
      token_sequence.each_with_index do |token_name, token_position|

        # The token definition describes how to recognize part of a string as a match. Typical
        # tokens include country, city and region names
        token_definition = $token_definitions[token_name]  
        match_function = token_definition[:match_function]

        # This logic optimizes out repeated calls to the same match function
        if token_position == 0 and match_cache.has_key?(token_name)
          token_result = match_cache[token_name]
        else
          # The meat of the algorithm, checks the ending of the current string against the
          # token testing function, eg seeing if it matches a country name
          token_result = send(match_function, text, token_index, token_result)
          if token_position == 0
            match_cache[token_name] = token_result
          end
        end

        if !token_result
          # The string doesn't match this token, so the sequence as a whole isn't a match
          break
        else
          # The current token did match, so move backwards through the string to the start of
          # the matched portion, and see if the preceding words match the next required token
          token_index = token_result[:found_tokens][0][:start_index]-1
        end
      end

      # We got through the whole sequence and all the tokens match, so we have a winner!
      if token_result
        current_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
        break
      end
    end

    if !token_result
      # None of the sequences matched, so back up a word and start over again
      ignored_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    else
      # We found a matching sequence, so add the information to the result
      result.push(token_result)
      found_tokens = token_result[:found_tokens]
      current_index = found_tokens[0][:start_index]-1
    end

  end

  # Reverse the result so it's in the order that the locations occured in the text
  result.reverse!

  return result

end

# Functions that look at a small portion of the text, and try to identify any location identifiers

# Caches the countries and regions tables in memory
$countries_cache = {}
$is_countries_cache_setup = false

def setup_countries_cache()

  if $is_countries_cache_setup then return end

  select = 'SELECT * FROM countries'
  hashes = select_as_hashes(select, DSTKConfig::DATABASE)

  hashes.each do |hash|
    last_word = hash['last_word'].downcase
    if !$countries_cache.has_key?(last_word)
      $countries_cache[last_word] = []
    end
    $countries_cache[last_word].push(hash)
  end

  $is_countries_cache_setup = true

end

$regions_cache = {}
$is_regions_cache_setup = false

def setup_regions_cache()

  if $is_regions_cache_setup then return end

  select = 'SELECT * FROM regions'
  hashes = select_as_hashes(select, DSTKConfig::DATABASE)

  hashes.each do |hash|
    last_word = hash['last_word'].downcase
    if !$regions_cache.has_key?(last_word)
      $regions_cache[last_word] = []
    end
    $regions_cache[last_word].push(hash)
  end


  $is_regions_cache_setup = true

end

# Translates a two-letter country code into a readable name
def get_country_name_from_code(country_code)
  if !country_code then return nil end
  setup_countries_cache()
  result = country_code
  $countries_cache.each do |last_word, countries|
    countries.each do |row|
      if row['country_code'] and row['country_code'].downcase == country_code.downcase
        result = row['country']
      end
    end
  end
  result
end

# Matches the current fragment against our database of countries
def is_country(text, text_starting_index, previous_result)

  current_word = ''
  current_index = text_starting_index
  pulled_word_count = 0
  found_row = nil

  # Walk backwards through the current fragment, pulling out words and seeing if they match
  # the country names we know about
  while pulled_word_count < DSTKConfig::WORD_MAX do
    pulled_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    pulled_word_count += 1
    if current_word == ''
      # This is the first time through, so the full word is just the one we pulled
      current_word = pulled_word
      # Make a note of the real end of the word, ignoring any trailing whitespace
      word_end_index = (text_starting_index-end_skipped)

      # We've indexed the locations by the word they end with, so find all of them
      # that have the current word as a suffix
      last_word = pulled_word.downcase
      if !$countries_cache.has_key?(last_word)
        break
      end
      candidate_dicts = $countries_cache[last_word]

      name_map = {}
      candidate_dicts.each do |candidate_dict|
        name = candidate_dict['country'].downcase
        name_map[name] = candidate_dict
      end
    else
      current_word = pulled_word+' '+current_word
    end

    # This happens if we've walked backwards all the way to the start of the string
    if current_word == ''
      return nil
    end

    # If the first letter of the name is lower case, then it can't be the start of a country
    # Somewhat arbitrary, but for my purposes it's better to miss some ambiguous ones like this
    # than to pull in erroneous words as countries (eg thinking the 'uk' in .co.uk is a country)
    if current_word[0].chr =~ /[a-z]/
      next
    end

    name_key = current_word.downcase
    if name_map.has_key?(name_key)
      found_row = name_map[name_key]
    end

    if found_row
      # We've found a valid country name
      break
    end

    if current_index < 0
      # We've walked back to the start of the string
      break
    end

  end 

  if !found_row 
    # We've walked backwards through the current words, and haven't found a good country match
    return nil
  end

  # Were there any tokens found already in the sequence? Unlikely with countries, but for
  # consistency's sake I'm leaving the logic in
  if !previous_result
    current_result = {
      :found_tokens => [],
    }
  else
    current_result = previous_result
  end

  country_code = found_row['country_code']
  lat = found_row['lat']
  lon = found_row['lon']

  # Prepend all the information we've found out about this location to the start of the :found_tokens
  # array in the result
  current_result[:found_tokens].unshift({
    :type => :COUNTRY,
    :code => country_code,
    :lat => lat,
    :lon => lon,
    :matched_string => current_word,
    :start_index => (current_index+1),
    :end_index => word_end_index 
  })

  return current_result

end

# Looks through our database of 2 million towns and cities around the world to locate any that match the
# words at the end of the current text fragment
def is_city(text, text_starting_index, previous_result)

  # If we're part of a sequence, then use any country or region information to narrow down our search
  country_code = nil
  region_code = nil
  if previous_result
    found_tokens = previous_result[:found_tokens]
    found_tokens.each do |found_token|
      type = found_token[:type]
      if type == :COUNTRY:
        country_code = found_token[:code]
      elsif type == :REGION:
        region_code = found_token[:code]
      end
    end
  end

  current_word = ''
  current_index = text_starting_index
  pulled_word_count = 0
  found_row = nil
  while pulled_word_count < DSTKConfig::WORD_MAX do
    pulled_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    pulled_word_count += 1

    if current_word == ''
      current_word = pulled_word
      word_end_index = (text_starting_index-end_skipped)

      select = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE last_word='"+pulled_word.downcase+"'"

      if country_code
        select += " AND country='"+country_code.downcase+"'"
      end

      if region_code
        select += " AND region_code='"+region_code.upcase.strip+"'"
      end

      # There may be multiple cities with the same name, so pick the one with the largest population
      select += ' ORDER BY population;'

      hashes = select_as_hashes(select, DSTKConfig::DATABASE)

      name_map = {}
      hashes.each do |hash|
        name = hash['city'].downcase
        name_map[name] = hash
      end

    else
      current_word = pulled_word+' '+current_word
    end

    if current_word == ''
      return nil
    end

    if current_word[0].chr =~ /[a-z]/
      next
    end

    name_key = current_word.downcase
    if name_map.has_key?(name_key)
      found_row = name_map[name_key]
    end

    if found_row
      break
    end

    if current_index < 0
      break
    end

  end

  if !found_row
    return nil
  end

  if !previous_result
    current_result = {
      :found_tokens => [],
    }
  else
    current_result = previous_result
  end

  lat = found_row['lat']
  lon = found_row['lon']
  country_code = found_row['country'].downcase

  current_result[:found_tokens].unshift( {
    :type => :CITY,
    :lat => lat,
    :lon => lon,
    :country_code => country_code,
    :matched_string => current_word,
    :start_index => (current_index+1),
    :end_index => word_end_index 
  })

  return current_result

end

# This looks for sub-regions within countries. At the moment the only values in the database are for US states
def is_region(text, text_starting_index, previous_result)

  # Narrow down the search by country, if we already have it
  country_code = nil
  if previous_result
    found_tokens = previous_result[:found_tokens]
    found_tokens.each do |found_token|
      type = found_token[:type]
      if type == :COUNTRY
        country_code = found_token[:code]
      end
    end
  end

  current_word = ''
  current_index = text_starting_index
  pulled_word_count = 0
  found_row = nil
  while pulled_word_count < DSTKConfig::WORD_MAX do
    pulled_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    pulled_word_count += 1
    if current_word == ''
      current_word = pulled_word
      word_end_index = (text_starting_index-end_skipped)

      last_word = pulled_word.downcase
      if !$regions_cache.has_key?(last_word)
        break
      end

      all_candidate_dicts = $regions_cache[last_word]
      if country_code
        candidate_dicts = []
        all_candidate_dicts.each do |possible_dict|
          candidate_country = possible_dict['country_code']
          if candidate_country.downcase() == country_code.downcase():
            candidate_dicts << possible_dict
          end
        end
      else
        candidate_dicts = all_candidate_dicts
      end

      name_map = {}
      candidate_dicts.each do |candidate_dict|
        name = candidate_dict['region'].downcase
        name_map[name] = candidate_dict
      end

    else
      current_word = pulled_word+' '+current_word
    end

    if current_word == ''
      return nil
    end

    if current_word[0].chr =~ /[a-z]/
      next
    end

    name_key = current_word.downcase
    if name_map.has_key?(name_key)
      found_row = name_map[name_key]
    end

    if found_row
      break
    end

    if current_index < 0
      break
    end

  end

  if !found_row
    return nil
  end

  if !previous_result
    current_result = {
      :found_tokens => [],
    }
  else
    current_result = previous_result
  end

  region_code = found_row['region_code']

  lat = found_row['lat']
  lon = found_row['lon']
  country_code = found_row['country_code'].downcase

  current_result[:found_tokens].unshift( {
    :type => :REGION,
    :code => region_code,
    :lat => lat,
    :lon => lon,
    :country_code => country_code,
    :matched_string => current_word,
    :start_index => (current_index+1),
    :end_index=> word_end_index 
  })

  return current_result

end

# A special case - used to look for 'at' or 'in' before a possible location word. This helps me be more certain
# that it really is a location in this context. Think 'the New York Times' vs 'in New York' - with the latter
# fragment we can be pretty sure it's talking about a location
def is_location_word(text, text_starting_index, previous_result)

  current_index = text_starting_index
  current_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
  word_end_index = (text_starting_index-end_skipped)
  if current_word == ''
    return nil
  end

  current_word.downcase!

  if !DSTKConfig::LOCATION_WORDS.has_key?(current_word)
    return nil
  end

  return previous_result

end

def is_postal_code(text, text_starting_index, previous_result)
  # Narrow down the search by country, if we already have it
  country_code = nil
  if previous_result
    found_tokens = previous_result[:found_tokens]
    found_tokens.each do |found_token|
      type = found_token[:type]
      if type == :COUNTRY
        country_code = found_token[:code]
      end
    end
  end

  current_word = ''
  current_index = text_starting_index
  pulled_word_count = 0
  found_rows = nil
  while pulled_word_count < DSTKConfig::WORD_MAX do
    pulled_word, current_index, end_skipped = pull_word_from_end(text, current_index)
    pulled_word_count += 1
    if current_word == ''
      current_word = pulled_word
      word_end_index = (text_starting_index-end_skipped)

      last_word = pulled_word.downcase

      select = "SELECT * FROM postal_codes"
      select += " WHERE last_word='"+pulled_word.downcase+"'"
      select += " OR last_word='"+pulled_word.upcase+"'"

      if country_code
        select += " AND country_code='"+country_code.upcase+"'"
      end

      candidate_dicts = select_as_hashes(select, DSTKConfig::DATABASE)

      name_map = {}
      candidate_dicts.each do |candidate_dict|
        name = candidate_dict['postal_code'].downcase
        if !name_map[name] then name_map[name] = [] end
        name_map[name] << candidate_dict
      end

    else
      current_word = pulled_word+' '+current_word
    end

    if current_word == ''
      return nil
    end

    if current_word[0].chr =~ /[a-z]/
      next
    end

    name_key = current_word.downcase
    if name_map.has_key?(name_key)
      found_rows = name_map[name_key]
    end

    if found_rows
      break
    end

    if current_index < 0
      break
    end

  end

  if !found_rows
    return nil
  end

  # Confirm the postal code against the country suffix
  found_row = nil
  if country_code
    found_rows.each do |row|
      if row['country_code'] == country_code
        found_row = row
        break
      end
    end
  end

  if !found_row
    return nil
  end

  # Also pull in the prefixed region, if there is one
  region_result = is_region(text, current_index, nil)
  if region_result
    region_token = region_result[:found_tokens][0]
    region_code = region_token[:code]
    if found_row['region_code'] == region_code
      current_index = region_token[:start_index]-1
      current_word = region_token[:matched_string] + ' ' + current_word
    end
  end

  if !found_row
    return nil
  end

  if !previous_result
    current_result = {
      :found_tokens => [],
    }
  else
    current_result = previous_result
  end

  region_code = found_row['region_code']

  lat = found_row['lat']
  lon = found_row['lon']
  country_code = found_row['country_code'].downcase
  region_code = found_row['region_code'].downcase
  postal_code = found_row['postal_code'].downcase

  current_result[:found_tokens].unshift( {
    :type => :POSTAL_CODE,
    :code => postal_code,
    :lat => lat,
    :lon => lon,
    :region_code => region_code,
    :country_code => country_code,
    :matched_string => current_word,
    :start_index => (current_index+1),
    :end_index=> word_end_index 
  })

  return current_result

end

# Characters to ignore when pulling out words
WHITESPACE = " \t'\",.-/\n\r<>!?".split(//).to_set

$tokenized_words = {}

# Walks backwards through the text from the end, pulling out a single unbroken sequence of non-whitespace
# characters, trimming any whitespace off the end
def pull_word_from_end(text, index, use_cache=true)

  if use_cache and $tokenized_words.has_key?(index)
    return $tokenized_words[index]
  end

  found_word = ''
  current_index = index
  end_skipped = 0
  while current_index>=0 do
    current_char = text[current_index].chr
    current_index -= 1

    if WHITESPACE.include?(current_char)

      if found_word == ''
        end_skipped += 1
        next
      else
        current_index += 1
        break
      end

    end

    found_word << current_char
  end

  # reverse the result (since we're appending for efficiency's sake)
  found_word.reverse!

  result = [found_word, current_index, end_skipped]
  $tokenized_words[index] = result

  return result

end

# Converts the result of an SQL fetch into an associative dictionary, rather than a numerically indexed list
def get_hash_from_row(fields, row)
  d = {}

  fields.each_with_index do |field, index|
    value = row[index]
    d[field] = value
  end

  return d

end

# Returns the most specific token from the array
def get_most_specific_token(tokens)
  if !tokens then return nil end
  result = nil
  result_priority = nil
  tokens.each do |token|
    priority = $token_priorities[token[:type]]
    if !result or result_priority > priority
      result = token
      result_priority = priority
    end
  end
  result
end

# Returns the results of the SQL select statement as associative arrays/hashes
def select_as_hashes(select, database_name)

  begin

    conn = get_database_connection(database_name)

    Thread.critical = true

    res = conn.exec('BEGIN')
    res.clear
    res = conn.exec('DECLARE myportal CURSOR FOR '+select)
    res.clear

    res = conn.exec('FETCH ALL in myportal')

    fields = res.fields
    rows = res.result

    res = conn.exec('CLOSE myportal')
    res = conn.exec('END')

    result = []
    rows.each do |row|
      hash = get_hash_from_row(fields, row)
      result.push(hash)
    end

  rescue PGError
    if conn
      printf(STDERR, conn.error)
    else
      $stderr.puts 'select_as_hashes() - no connection for ' + database_name
    end
    if conn
      conn.close
    end
    $connections[database_name] = nil
    exit(1)
  ensure
    Thread.critical = false
  end  

  return result

end

def get_database_connection(database_name)
  begin
    Thread.critical = true
    if !$connections[database_name]
      $connections[database_name] = PGconn.connect(DSTKConfig::HOST,
        DSTKConfig::PORT,
        '',
        '',
        database_name,
        DSTKConfig::USER,
        DSTKConfig::PASSWORD)
    end
  ensure
    Thread.critical = false
  end
  if !$connections[database_name]
    $stderr.puts "get_database_connection('#{database_name}') - Couldn't open connection"
  end
  $connections[database_name]
end

# Types of locations we'll be looking for
$token_definitions = {
  :COUNTRY => {
    :match_function => :is_country
  },
  :CITY => {
    :match_function => :is_city
  },
  :REGION => {
    :match_function => :is_region
  },
  :LOCATION_WORD => {
    :match_function => :is_location_word
  },
  :POSTAL_CODE => {
    :match_function => :is_postal_code
  }
}

# Particular sequences of those location words that give us more confidence they're actually describing
# a place in the text, and aren't coincidental names (eg 'New York Times')
$token_sequences = [
  [ :POSTAL_CODE, :REGION, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :REGION, :POSTAL_CODE, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :POSTAL_CODE, :CITY, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :POSTAL_CODE, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :CITY, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :CITY, :REGION ],
  [ :REGION, :COUNTRY ],
  [ :COUNTRY ],
  [ :LOCATION_WORD, :REGION ], # Regions and cities are too common as words to use without additional evidence
  [ :LOCATION_WORD, :CITY ]
]

# Location identifiers in order of decreasing specificity
$token_priorities = {
 :POSTAL_CODE => 0,
 :CITY => 1,
 :REGION => 2,
 :COUNTRY => 3,
}

if __FILE__ == $0

  require 'json'

  test_text = <<-TEXT
Spain 
Italy
Bulgaria
Foofofofof
New Zealand
Barcelona, Spain
Wellington New Zealand
I've been working on the railroad, all the live-long day! The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog in Alabama
I'm mentioning Los Angeles here, but without California or CA right after it, it won't be detected. If I talk about living in Wisconsin on the other hand, that 'in' gives the algorithm extra evidence it's actually a location.
It should still pick up more qualified names like Amman Jordan or Atlanta, Georgia though!
Dallas, TX or New York, NY
It should now pick up Queensland, Australia, or even NSW, Australia!
Postal codes like QLD 4002, Australia, QC H3W, Canada, 2608 Lillehammer, Norway, or CA 94117, USA are supported too.
TEXT

  puts "Analyzing '#{test_text}'"
  puts "Found locations:"

  locations = find_locations_in_text(test_text)  
  locations.each_with_index do |location_info, index|
    found_tokens = location_info[:found_tokens]
    location = get_most_specific_token(found_tokens)
    match_start_index = found_tokens[0][:start_index]
    match_end_index = found_tokens[found_tokens.length-1][:end_index]
    matched_string = test_text[match_start_index..match_end_index]
    result = {
      'type' => location[:type],
      'name' => location[:matched_string],
      'latitude' => location[:lat].to_s,
      'longitude' => location[:lon].to_s,
      'start_index' => location[:start_index].to_s,
      'end_index' => location[:end_index].to_s,
      'matched_string' => matched_string,
      'country' => location[:country_code],
      'code' => location[:code],
    }
    puts result.to_json
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the call, or ask first before trying:

```
Thread.respond_to(:critical=) and Thread.critical = true
```

That being said, since `Thread.critical=` was removed in Ruby 1.9 it's pretty safe to trash that code entirely. Anyone running Ruby 1.8.x is living dangerously.

Unless you have a specific requirement to support 1.8.x, you'll have to delete the calls and use an alternative.

The purpose of `critical=` is to prevent pre-emption of the thread by another. That's a really heavy-handed way to synchronize threads, and dangerous enough that Ruby pulled support for it lest that start to become more pervasive.

What you probably want is a [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Mutex.html) if you need to lock a resource. There's no obviously shared resources here *unless* `get_database_connection` returns one. It doesn't seem to as the connection is closed on error.

This code is full of some seriously suspect things, like using `$connections`, a global variable, and hard-exiting the whole process on failure. You may want to do a more thorough investigation as to what the purpose of the `critical` lock was in the first place.

Comment: I updated the entire code, maybe you can help me see if it is fine to remove all the Thread.critical. What about the `code`ensureThread.critical = false end`code` can I remove it too?

Comment: There's now tons more code to review, which is off-topic here, but [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) can accommodate. I'd **strongly** avoid using global variables in any form in here, especially if using threads.

Comment: You should be able to remove both references to `Thread.critical=` but I would test this code heavily. A lot of it is really not that great and needs to be refactored.